# Axial skeletal system

Tags: human-biology

I was curious about a fact given in my biology textbook as to why the Japanese have  3 pairs o floating ribs unlike the rest who have just two?

Answer (score 2):

Because your textbook is probably worded poorly.

It appears that the Japanese (and several other ethnic groups) apparently have a [higher proclivity for the 10th rib to be a true floating rib](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/False_ribs#Tenth_rib), but **every** ethnic group has the chance of having a floating 10th rib.

With that said, the one McGraw-Hill book cited in the Wiki article is the ***only*** source I've seen for this higher morphology rate. I, personally, wouldn't trust just one source, and (if true) the rate may not be much higher.